# I'm getting a "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" on my discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

ive tried multiple sites with answers and so far none of them have worked. here is the code:

```
    // Run dotenv
    require('dotenv').config();
    // Import libraries
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Discord.Client();

    // Event listener when a user connectd to the server
    client.on('ready', () => {
        console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    });

    // Event listener when a user sends a message in the chat
    client.on('message', msg => {
    
    // We check the message content and look for the word "ping", so we can have the bot respong "pong"
    client.on('message', msg => {
      if (msg.content === 'ping') {
        msg.channel.send('pong');
    
           }; 

    });

    client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

this is the error I'm getting:

```
    C:\Users\creep\discord-greeter-bot\bot.js:24
    client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN)


    SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    [90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:16)[39m
    [90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:27)[39m
    [90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)[39m
    [90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)[39m
    [90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)[39m
    [90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)[39m
    [90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47[39m
```

so according to this code, my error is on the last line. I'm not sure how else to edit it because I've tried rearranging the brackets, adding more, changing the code entirely, and rewriting it from scratch. I don't understand which part of my code is incorrect and I've been struggling for a few days
any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit: it was working before then i added all the "//" messages and it just stopped. im not sure why but i dont think they would have an effect. i also changed the token but i did replace the one in the .env file with the new one.

Comment: your first `client.on('message', msg => {` is never closed, so you're missing `});` at the end. Not sure why you have two of these listeners though...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `client.on('message', msg => {` twice in your code, and you only close it once, so at the end of the file, you have an open `({`, so it should work if you remove one of them.

As for the comments with `//` affecting it, those comments are literally removed from the code before compiling it, and will have no effect on how the code runs.

Comment: oh my god i duplicated one of the ```client.on``` messages i wouldve never noticed that. thank you! edit: it worked lol